# Handling missing resources with Apache HTTP in Java

Tags: java, url, apache-httpclient-4.x

I'm using [HttpEntity](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/HttpEntity.html) from Apache library to download files from URLs. I.e.

```
String url="http://www.stackoverflow.com/question/ask/idontexist.jpg";
String user_agent=...; //I know, I can use the default value, but this is what I do actually!


HttpClient httpclient =new AutoRetryHttpClient(new DefaultServiceUnavailableRetryStrategy(5, 500));

HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url);
httpget.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
httpget.setHeader("User-Agent", user_agent);

HttpEntity entity = httpclient.execute(httpget).getEntity(); 

InputStream is = entity.getContent();
```

Now. If I save the resource from the `InputStream` through a `FileOutputStream` I get a file named `idontexist.jpg`, but it has no content (as expected).

How can I verify that the returned `InputStream` has no content or that the requested resource pointed by the URL doesn't exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should first get HttpResponse object with

```
HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(httpget);
```

Then you can get status code with

```
int statusCode = httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
```

and, if the resource is found, get http entity with

```
HttpEntity entity = httpResponse.getEntity();
```

Hope this helps,

Regards.

Comment: what is the statusCode for "resource is found"?

Comment: @mat_boy Resource not found is 404. Take a look [here](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) for a full reference.

Comment: When I use line `httpclient.execute(httpget)` I get: _Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Invalid use of BasicClientConnManager: connection still allocated.
Make sure to release the connection before allocating another one._ It is strange, there should be no difference w.r.t. `httpclient.execute(httpget).getEntity()`

Comment: @mat_boy are you sure you are calling httpclient.execute() only once?

Comment: No, I use it more than one time. It seems that something goes wrong when I do the second call to the `httpclient.execute`. I believe that there is something that must be closed! I'll let you know!

Comment: @mat_boy Try with `EntityUtils.consumeQuietly(entity)` to consume all your last entity before making a new call to execute(). In alternative, you can allocate a new HttpClient for each call. See [this](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/connmgmt.html#d5e619) for `BasicClientConnectionManager` details.

Comment: Yes, you are right! Your solution is more elegant than the one I'm using now. I.e. when I get a **404 code** I call `httpResponse.getEntity.getContent().close();` to close the associated `InputStream`.